# Listbox circular list and automatic rotation in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, listbox, rotation

I have a collection of elements which I display correctly inside a listbox. I'd like do animate the list so that it displays like the rolling credits at the end of a movie. Besides, I want to make the list circular, so that when the last item rolls in the visible portion of the listbox, it show the first item next. Frankly I don't know where to start.

Thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: Please read [Dr.WPF ItemsControl: 'N' is for Natural User Interface](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/08/05/itemscontrol-n-is-for-natural-user-interface/). Studying the LoopPanel Sample Application could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use animation for this.

XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="_canvas">
    <ListBox Name="_listBox" Loaded="OnListBoxLoaded" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5, 20, 5, 0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="10" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _listBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "FFF", "EEE", "DDD", "CCC", "BBB", "AAA" }; ;
    }

    private void OnListBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();   
        doubleAnimation.From = -(sender as FrameworkElement).ActualHeight;
        doubleAnimation.To = _marqueeHeight;   
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;   
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));   
        _listBox.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, doubleAnimation);

        _canvas.Clip = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, _canvas.ActualWidth, _marqueeHeight));
    }

    private double _marqueeHeight = 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very a good start, but how do I make the list "circular"? That is, I want to see the first element after the last, and consider that the list item count is dinamically changing.....

Comment: With circular, do you mean with no gap between first and last item? What should happen when list is updated, start from first item?